# Value in TextField throws java.lang.NumberFormatException error

Tags: java, if-statement, parseint, java.lang.class

So this is how I have my code (of course, not finished because I don't want to do any other work until I can figure out why I'm getting the error). It compiles no problem but when I try to run it I get a *`java.lang.NumberFormatException`* for my first line, not really sure why?

```
 if (Integer.parseInt(subtotalTextField.getText()) <= 200)
 {
    discountTextField.setText("2");
 }
    else
 {
 }
```

Comment: Trim that string before parsing it. Then all NFE's after that are due to user (input) error.

Answer (score 4):

Because `subtotalTextField.getText()` returns something that is not parsable to `int`, in exception message it should show what was the value that was passed to `parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

What's returned is not a String perhaps? Don't chain it, check for null and do

```
Object val = subtotalTextField.getText();
if (val != null)
    String txt = val.toString();
```

Comment: It must be a string otherwise there would be a compile-time error (and `getText` usually means string). `NumberFormatException`s usually indicate that a string can't be parsed as an int (or other numeric type).

Comment: It is a string, but not an integer representation

Comment: Not in Android for example - there it will return Spannable

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the text entered in the textfield can't be parsed to an Integer. This means that your textfield contains characters i.e. "2s" .

if you want to avoid this error everytime an user enters a non-valid Integer, surround it with a try-catch clause.

```
try{
// Try to parse to Integer

}catch(NumberFormatException e) {
// Thing to do when a user enters non-valid Integer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible value for subtotalTextField.getText() that I can think about it

```
 subtotalTextField.getText() = null; // or

 subtotalTextField.getText() = "";  // or

 subtotalTextField.getText() = "Any non passable String"; // a ,b c .. 1a ,2a ... etc
```

If you could make sure user is entered value is valid number by any validation. No problem start with your logic.